# Guzzle getBody() after request return posted body

Tags: guzzle6, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 6.3. I'm trying to post a data with a header.
This is my code:

```
$headers = [
  'content-type' => 'application/json',
  'Accept' => 'application/json'
];

$request = new Psr7\Request('post', 'product', $headers, json_encode($data));
$res = $this->http->send($request);
$resData = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);
```

The response body (`$resData`) is always equal to the posted one (`$data`).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$resData = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

Otherwise (if it doesn't help) check what your API endpoint returns.